# Swift bool changes by itself

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, eventkit

I have this weird bug. I have a global `Bool` called `CalendarAccess`:

```
var EventStore: EKEventStore!
var Calendar: NSCalendar!
var CalendarAccessRequestComplete = false
var _CalendarAccess = false
var CalendarAccess: Bool {
    set(value)
    {
        _CalendarAccess = value;
    }
    get {
        return _CalendarAccess;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I made a setter and getter for it so I could put a breakpoint to see where it is being set. I did that and every single time I hit the breakpoint the value is `true`. I'm sure I never set the `_CalendarAccess` directly because this variable was called just `CalendarAccess` until just now.

But, when I do the following in a view controller, `CalendarAccess` is `false`!

```
@IBAction func saveEvent(_ sender: Any) {

    if(CalendarAccess)
    {
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: EventStore)
        event.title = "My Event"
        event.startDate = Date();
        event.endDate = Calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date(), options: .matchFirst)!
        event.notes = "A note"
        event.calendar = EventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do
        {
            try EventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch
        {
            print("Unable to save event")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorAlert(title: "No calendar access", text: "Please give the app access to your calendar. You can do that in your iOS device's settings.")
    }
}
```

I have no idea how this even is possible - the variable is a global that doesn't have anything to do with any view or controller.

The controller the last code block is from is presented modally, if that information is useful at all.

**EDIT:** `CalendarAccess` is set in only one place (AppDelegate):

```
func updateCalendarAccess()
{
    Calendar = NSCalendar.current as NSCalendar!
    CalendarAccessRequestComplete = false

    EventStore = EKEventStore()
    EventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
        (access: Bool, e: Error?) in

        CalendarAccessRequestComplete = true

        CalendarAccess = access;

        return

    })

    while(!CalendarAccessRequestComplete) { }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    updateCalendarAccess()

    return true
}
```

**EDIT:** I get these messages when I tap the button that calls the `@IBAction func saveEvent`:

```
2017-02-17 13:58:00.980237 Calendar[16695:5163026] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-17 13:58:00.989165 Calendar[16695:5163026] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

**EDIT:** When I dismiss the modally presented view controller (the one with the `saveEvent` func) and log the value of `CalendarAccess`, it's true again. And the setter breakpoint isn't hit.

**EDIT:** It seems like the value of `_CalendarAccess` goes back to the initial value when I present the VC. If I change `var _CalendarAccess = false` to `var _CalendarAccess = true` it is true when the VC is presented. Also, the `Calendar` variable is `nil` when the VC is presented, but not otherwise.

Comment: What *exactly* makes you think that `_CalendarAccess` becomes true? Can you post a (minimal) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem? Is the breakpoint in the setter method hit? If yes – what is the call stack? Perhaps it is just debugger displaying garbage? Add `print(_CalendarAccess)` to both setter and getter.

Comment: So I added a `print(_CalendarAccess)` below the `_CalendarAccess = true` line. That prints `true` one time before the the `saveEvent` function is called. But still, I get the error alert.

Comment: Your code in func saveEvent interrogates CalenderAccess. The getter returns the value of _CalendarAccess which you have set to false. Unless you actually set _CalendarAccess to true it will always return false.

Comment: @Magnas, I do set the `CalendarAccess`.

Comment: You said you print **_CalendarAccess** after you set it to true, and then get true. Where is the problem??

Comment: @edvinHolm: I can see no `_CalendarAccess = true` in your code ... Please have a look at how to create a [mcve], i.e. some code that *we* can compile and reproduce the problem.

Comment: The variable is set in other places in the code base. It is always set to true, which is proven by the `print`, but in the `saveEvent` function I get false.

Comment: @MartinR, it's hard to do because I'd probably not get the same result then.

Comment: @edvinHolm: Then how do you expect that we can solve your problem? A variable does not "change itself".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135969/discussion-between-edvinholm-and-donmag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project had same-named framework included, which was causing the compiler to look in multiple places for the same values. Remove framework, problem solved :)